# Kendoui treeview expand when scrolling content

Tags: kendo-ui, treeview

Is it possible with a similar behavior when scrolling content like Bootstrap scrollspy, affix.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy (left sidebar)

That is expanding nodes in treeview when user scrolls down the content page.

/S

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly implement something like that, but it does require quite a bit of custom code. You can use the treeview's [expand](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/treeview#methods-expand), expandPath and [collapse](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/treeview#methods-collapse) methods to expand/collapse nodes. Then you need some sort of marker elements on the page which map to certain tree nodes and trigger the expand/collapse actions. Then you need a way to figure out if your marker element is visible (you could probably use something like [jquery.inview](https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview) or maybe use `$.scrollTop()`).